# How to use equal Ignore Cases in Dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, dataweave

I want to check equal Ignore cases in dataweave

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
--- 
    Order:
    {
        Channel:payload.Order.@EnterpriseCode,
        Code:payload.Order.@OrderNo,

        (Status:payload.Order.@Status) when (payload.Order.@Status== "complete") ,

        OrderLines:{
            ((payload.Order.OrderLines.*OrderLine default []) map {
            OrderLine:{
                EntryNumber:$.@PrimeLineNo,
                Status:$.@Status,
                Quantity:$.@OrderedQty
            }
        })
    }

    }
```

I Want to ignore cases while checking when condition. How to achieve it in Mule dataweave

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `upper` function like so:

```
{
 (Field1: payload.Field1) when (upper payload.Field1) == "COMPLETE"
}
```

Comment: But how to check format of incoming value in payload? we have to ignore the cases

Comment: just uppercase the incoming value and compare it an uppercase constant. That way they both will always be uppercase, so case is technically ignored.